# Delivery of emails is delayed

Tags: exchange-2013

The mails from my exchange servers usually get this response "Delivery is delayed to these recipients or groups". why is it like that

"This message hasn't been delivered yet. Delivery will continue to be attempted.
The server will keep trying to deliver this message for the next 1 days, 19 hours and 49 minutes. You'll be notified if the message can't be delivered by that time".